# How to avoid the overflow of the value from one column to another column in EXCEL using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to wrap the whole content of a cell/column within the same cell/column so the value does not overflow to another column.
Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is confusing: Is this an issue with a Excel Sheet or with a ASP.Net Table?

Comment: What C# library are you using to access the Excel sheet? Some libraries are designed only to access the data of sheets and have no formatting control.

Comment: Whenever I hit get button in my application it generates a excel file, there is a column in Excel file whose value is overflowing to another column on right. I wanted to keep the content of the column within the same column.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just formatting? Do you need to add 'wrap' to cell formatting and just dbl-click the column so it's wide enough?